# Efficient way to find duplicate object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, unique

I am working with angular4. I need to display a list with unique values.

When accessing an API I get an array, from that array I need to display only unique data. I will be accessing that api at certain time interval and I need to update list only if new data is present.

`response= [{"id":"0DRDCH03DR51GGJGJNP80F7XZ8","value":"36af1784bec4_566601260"},{"id":"0DRDCFYGM2CAHAXYK96BPT9RHV","value":"36af1784bec4_566601140"},...]`

```
listData = [];
for(let data of response) {
    let tempValue = {id: '', time: ''};
    let value = data.value.split('_')
    if (value.length==2) {
        if(value[value.length-1].length==2) {
            tempValue.id = value[0];
            tempValue.time = value[1];
        }
        let isPresent = false;
        if(this.listData.length>0){
            for(let value of this.listData){
                if(value.time===tempValue.time){
                    isPresent = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!isPresent) {
            this.listData.push(tempValue);
        }
    }

    }
```

the final listData

```
listData = [{id:'36af1784bec4', time: '566601140'},...]
```

The above function does give me a unique `listData` array. I tried using `array.filter` and `new Set` but could not achieve the desired result.

I would like to know if there is an efficient way to do this.

Comment: If your definition of new data is new `id` and `value`, then finding the existing of data may be more costly than updating the list regardless.

Comment: You can convert array to [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: @bigless I tried converting to `Set` and tried using `.has` but it always returned `true` even when the `listData` was empty

Comment: @gurvinder372 the response that I am getting has `id` and `value`, but new `listData` is `value.split('_')` and `value[0] is id` and `value[1] is time`. `listData = [{id: '36af1784bec4', time: '566601260'},...]`

Comment: @Tony Roczz yea I was naive. its probably based on same reference...

Comment: @TonyRoczz This is precisely the point. You still need to do all this and more - just to check the existence of similar data. And in the worst case scenario, you may still have to update the list. I don't see any improvements  in not updating the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove duplicate by the following code.

```
var obj = {};

for ( var i=0, len=response.length; i < len; i++ )
    obj[response[i]['id']] = response[i]; // if id Duplicate otherwise use value if the check on value.

response = new Array();
for ( var key in obj )
    response.push(obj[key]);

console.log(response); // listData
```

**Edit:**

and if you want to use a complete check of your prop then you can go for this one

```
function removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) {
    return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
        return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
    });
}


console.log(removeDuplicates(response,['id','value'])); // for id or value use only 'id' or 'value' in second parameter.
```

Comment: He wants to find dup objects not just objects of dup ids

Comment: not an optimised solution, you are looping twice, check my solution :)

Comment: think about the input with thousands of unique property, will you loop that many times twice?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do

```
for(let data of response) {
    if(!this.listData.find((ldata) => data.value.substring(data.value.lastIndexOf('_')+1) === ldata.time)) {
        let tempValue = {id: '', time: ''};
        let value = data.value.split('_')
        if (value.length==2) {
            if(value[value.length-1].length==2) {
                tempValue.id = value[0];
                tempValue.time = value[1];
            }
            this.listData.push(tempValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i would like to know why you are doing `data.lastIndexOf('_')+1`

Comment: sorry the check should be on the top, I thought it before splitting we can check for duplicate

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by `JSON.stringify` the objects like following :

```js
let response = [{
  "id": "0DRDCH03DR51GGJGJNP80F7XZ8",
  "value": "36af1784bec4_566601260"
}, {
  "id": "0DRDCFYGM2CAHAXYK96BPT9RHV",
  "value": "36af1784bec4_566601140"
}, {
  "id": "0DRDCH03DR51GGJGJNP80F7XZ8",
  "value": "36af1784bec4_566601260"
}]

let o = response.reduce((acc, cv) => {
  if (!acc[JSON.stringify(cv)]) {
    acc[JSON.stringify(cv)] = true; //something non-falsy
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

let res = Object.keys(o).map(x => JSON.parse(x));
console.log(res);
```

**Edit**
As [user3297291](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297291/user3297291) pointed out

> Might be helpful to note that JSON.stringify({ a: 1, b: 2}) !== JSON.stringify({ b: 2, a: 1 })

So the above will fail in that case.

A more optimised solution would be

```js
let response = [{
  "id": "0DRDCH03DR51GGJGJNP80F7XZ8",
  "value": "36af1784bec4_566601260"
}, {
  "id": "0DRDCFYGM2CAHAXYK96BPT9RHV",
  "value": "36af1784bec4_566601140"
}, {
  "id": "0DRDCH03DR51GGJGJNP80F7XZ8",
  "value": "36af1784bec4_566601260"
}];

let o = response.reduce((acc, cv) => {
  if (!acc[cv.value]) {
    acc[cv.value] = true; //something non-falsy
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

let res = Object.keys(o).map(x => {
  let t = x.split('_');
  return {
    id: t[0],
    time: t[1]
  };
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Might be helpful to note that `JSON.stringify({ a: 1, b: 2}) !== JSON.stringify({ b: 2, a: 1 })`

Comment: I found a pretty efficient way for this problem would be updating my solution

Answer (score 1):

For an **Optimised solution** (loop only once i.e. O(n))
use object property to check if property already added, by this way you will avoid looping to find if property already added.

**Below is the sample solution**

```js
let response = [{
    "id": "0DRDCH03DR51GGJGJNP80F7XZ8",
    "value": "36af1784bec4_566601260"
  }, {
    "id": "0DRDCH03DR51GGJGJNP80F7XZ8",
    "value": "36af1784bec4_566601260"
  }, {
    "id": "0DRDCFYGM2CAHAXYK96BPT9RHV",
    "value": "36af1784bec4_566601140"
  }],
  listData = [],
  tempObj = {};
for (let data of response) {
    let value = data.value.split('_');
  if (!tempObj.hasOwnProperty(value[1])) {
    tempObj[data.value[1]] = "";
    listData.push({
      id: value[0],
      time: value[1]
    });
  }
}

console.log(listData);
```

**Update**: based on comments, checking only for duplicate time value

Comment: I dont need to find if the property is already added. i need to avoid adding duplicate values of time. which is got after the split operation

Comment: logic would still remain same, currently i am checking complete value property

Comment: by checking, if property is already added, you can avoid looping through the output to check if this value already added.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `map` to collect the ids and then with a `filter` to remove the duplicates :

```js
const response= [{"id":"0DRDCH03DR51GGJGJNP80F7XZ8","value":"36af1784bec4_566601260"},{"id":"0DRDCFYGM2CAHAXYK96BPT9RHV","value":"36af1784bec4_566601140"}];

const ids = response.map(it => it.value.split('_')[0]).filter((it, i, arr) => i === arr.indexOf(it))

console.log(ids);
```

Or with a `reduce` :

```js
const response= [{"id":"0DRDCH03DR51GGJGJNP80F7XZ8","value":"36af1784bec4_566601260"},{"id":"0DRDCFYGM2CAHAXYK96BPT9RHV","value":"36af1784bec4_566601140"}];

const ids = response.reduce((acc, it) => {
  const id = it.value.split('_')[0];
  return acc.includes(id) ? acc : [...acc, id];
}, []);

console.log(ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of JavaScript allow for reliance on object structure to stay the same... Therefore we can now rely on stringifying and comparing the two strings:

```
JSON.stringify({id:0, name:foo}) === JSON.stringify({id:0, name:foo}) // true
```

So with an array of objects:

1. stringifying an object to test
2. looping through a collection of objects stringifying each
3. comparing the two

is helpful because you don't need to know key names. It just works on any object types...

```
arr = [{object}, {object2}, {etc...}]
test = JSON.stringify(obj);

for ( let i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++ ) {
  let testAgainst = JSON.stringify(arr[i]);
  if (test === testAgainst) { 
    console.log('matches');
  } else {
    console.log('no match');
  }
}
```

Now you'd be matching two strings. If I'm missing something please comment.

Comment: @Tony Roczz does this help as a modern, 2019 answer?